# XML diff algorithms

Tags: xml, algorithm

Are there any algorithms that could be used to compare XML files that are not ordered? Example:

```
<a>
    <b>Hello</b>
    <c>World</c>
</a>
```

is equal to:

```
<a>
    <c>World</c>
    <b>Hello</b>
</a>
```

Comment: Create a hash table and compare values? Seems like a naive way to do it, but might be all you'd need

Answer (score 0):

### One way to compare XML files that are not ordered is to give them the same order

Instead of just comparing the two XML, order them so they both have a consistent order (for example start to order them by tag name alphabeticaly), and only compare the ordered result

In this case, once you order it,

```
<a>
    <c>World</c>
    <b>Hello</b>
</a>
```

become

```
<a>
    <b>Hello</b>
    <c>World</c>
</a>
```

Then, you compare it to the first XML to see that they are identical